# PXE boot Live CD

Tags: ubuntu, pxe, tftp

I am trying to make possible remote Ubuntu boot. I have done one little thing, using this [article](https://debian-administration.org/article/478/Setting_up_a_server_for_PXE_network_booting)  , but there is one roughness. 
I would like to **boot Ubuntu Live CD** on my client and work in this half-OS (using option "Try Ubuntu") , while in this article one tells how to **install** Ubuntu Server.

Definitely, we need to raise DHCP and TFTP. I have done it, but there is problem in `/var/lib/tftpboot`.   In my case it looks like:

```
tree /var/lib/tftpboot/
/var/lib/tftpboot/
├── boot.txt
├── debian
│   └── etch
│       └── i386
│           ├── initrd.gz
│           └── linux
├── pxelinux.0
└── pxelinux.cfg
    └── default
```

but it is enough to install Ubuntu Server, while I need to run Ubuntu Live CD. Which files should I download and where to put them to make that possible?